# How do I put a limit between the ifs?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a little issue, my code prints the `if(RanNum >= 4)` and `if(RanNum >=8 )` together, but I just want to print `(RanNum >=8)`, I want to put a limit between then, but I don't know how, thank's in advance!

```
        int Min = 1;
        int Max = 10;
        int RanNum = Min + (int)(Math.random() * (Max - Min) );
        System.out.println(RanNum);
        if(RanNum <= 3){
                System.out.println("hello");
        }
        if(RanNum >= 4 ){
            System.out.println("four four four four four");
        }
        if(RanNum >= 8){
            System.out.println("here it is");
        }
```

Comment: Please specify exactly what your program should do. It looks like a simple "if  .. else if .. else ..." problem.

Comment: I wanted to create a limit between them as many as I wanted,  like "if RanNum is equal or smaller than 3 will print this,  if RanNum is equal or bigger than 4 will print that, if RanNum is equal or bigger than 8..." and there it goes, as much as I wanted, but with a limitation between them, showing where one begins and ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with your logic.  For example if `RanNum` is greater than 8 then it will also be greater than 4.  Use `else` if you want a branch of code that only runs when the `if` condition is not satisfied.

Use `if else` and re order the conditions

```
if(RanNum <= 3){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }else if(RanNum >= 8 ){
        System.out.println("here it is");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("four four four four four");
    }
```